# Evernote Android-Job setExact

Tags: android, evernote

I'm using the [Evernote Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) to schedule tasks.

Now I'm using the `setExact` method to trigger a task at a particular time

However, it does not trigger at the particular time.

This is my class which extends the Job Class

```
public class JobController extends Job {

public static final String TAG = "job_tag";

@Override
protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0,
            new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class), 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
            .setContentTitle("Android Job Demo")
            .setContentText("Notification from Android Job Demo App.")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setColor(Color.RED)
            .setLocalOnly(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat.from(getContext())
            .notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification);

    return Result.SUCCESS;
}

public static void setAlarm(long alertAt) {
    new JobRequest.Builder(JobController.TAG)
            .setExact(alertAt)
            .setPersisted(true)
            .build()
            .schedule();
  }
}
```

This is my Job Creator Class

```
public class JobCreator implements com.evernote.android.job.JobCreator {

@Override
public Job create(String tag) {
    switch (tag) {
        case JobController.TAG:
            return new JobController();
        default:
            return null;
    }
  }
}
```

And finally calling

```
 JobController.setAlarm(1498066440000L);
```

These are the logs:

```
Warning: job with tag job_tag scheduled over a year in the future
```

But `1498066440000` belongs to 2017

Comment: "The milliseconds specified are treated as offset from now, e.g. the job will run at `System.currentTimeMillis() + exactInMs`." https://github.com/evernote/android-job/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/evernote/android/job/JobRequest.java#L798

Comment: Oh, the log makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like mentioned in the comment it's an offset from now in milliseconds. Use `JobController.setAlarm(2_000L);` to start the job in 2 seconds.